# Upgrading to Beta 4

Tags: keystonejs

I have upgraded keystonejs from 3 to 4 per the instructions. Installed Jade and underscore. New db, got populated. When i start, no errors, waiting on port 3000. Just this error in browser

Cannot GET /

I've looked at the keystone.js and routes files in the demo project, can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors anywhere else? What about in the console which you are running keystone from? Does the `GET /` get logged in the console? Is there anything in the console on your browser (usually f12).

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird thing, there is not. It might be the dropping of Jade in 4. I added it back and was using consolidate to run jade and nunjucks. i might need to just use nunjucks and see if that is issue. Maybe it can't find a template to serve. Odd there is no error though.

Comment: You might have to change `view engine` to `pug` from `jade`, then, since the dependencies changed. You might also have to do `npm install` and `npm prune` to get stuff that Keystone 4 needs (and remove stuff no longer needed).